# Some data are not updated once a flagged post is deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, deleted-answers, flags

When a flagged answer in a question is deleted, some of the related data remains still. Such as;

- The points gained by the user that has answered the question.
- The answering user's name and answer date stays still (if the deleted post was the last) on the profile window questions tab.

//Edit the one below is either fixed or takes a long time to refresh I've found out as of today OP's accept rate is not a problem.

- And the OP's accept rate does not update (if flagged post was the only answer and got deleted accept rate still considers that question as not answered even if there was no possible answers except flagged and deleted post)
- And the badges of the answering user gained by that post (though it may be unfair to ask to return the badges...)

It's not a big deal, but also not a hard thing to solve either. Just seen one flagged answer got deleted but the related data remains still and now bugs me. Thanks for the work!

---

EDIT: Thanks to hardworking devs, these situations seems to be dealt with. Also as I said this is not a biggie, but a possible bug (OP's accept rate not updating but staying as not accepted) so I'd like if you don't vote as its simply a recommendation in past.

Comment: Accept rate is cached. I'm pretty sure the removal of votes from deleted posts happens during a scheduled task, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Tim I'm pretty sure votes aren't invalidated, in case the post is ever undeleted. (Plus, I have really old deleted posts with a non-zero score.) The rep gained/lost is invalidated, but only on rep-recalc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The points gained by the user that has answered the question.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) because the rep cap makes recalcs expensive. It's updated on a reputation recalc, which can ve trigerred manually at `/reputation` or by a mod.

> The answering user's name and answer date stays still (if the deleted post was the last) on the profile window questions tab.

Probably worth fixing.

> And the OP's accept rate does not update (if flagged post was the only answer and got deleted accept rate still considers that question as not answered even if there was no possible answers except flagged and deleted post)

Pretty sure this is just a result of a long cache, but I'm not sure.

> And the badges of the answering user gained by that post (though it may be unfair to ask to return the badges...)

Long standing SE policy is not to revoke badges except where there has been a huge coding bug. However, the next time the user earns the badge, it will not be reawarded (the old one is counted instead).