# Answer moved to superuser, reps not included in day's count, but upvotes are not being counted

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Some data are not updated once a flagged post is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104865/some-data-are-not-updated-once-a-flagged-post-is-deleted)

My day's reputation is below 200 ( not only upvotes, but rep from accepted answers as well. ) But I see that new upvotes are not being counted in the rep. I am assuming it is somewhow because of a 7 upvote answer being moved to superuser. But it shouldn't be happening this way right? Is this known?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean your rep on SO. Have you tried a recalc? (Go to [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation), scroll to the bottom and click the "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button.)

Comment: @AnnaLear - I know about the recalc thing, just wondering why it affects the day's upvotes as the day's rep is being shown fine and is still below 200 and it is only the whole reputation that is not reflecting the move.

Comment: My guess is that the answer is "it's updated after a recalc and works out in the end". Or "caching". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're looking at another rep storage strategy that would allow this to be fixed automatically - until then, it's by-design.